# How to access my iPhone's Bluetooth log to find last known connection of headphones?

Tags: iphone, ios, bluetooth

I lost my [Beats Powerbeats Pro](https://www.beatsbydre.com/earphones/powerbeats-pro) headphones.  The last time I remembered using them was at the grocery store.  I called the grocery store and they didn't find any but I really don't think I left them there.  I want to do some investigation before I give up.  I don't expect there to be any charge left in them as I tried connecting in my car and in my house.

**My goal is to somehow get access to my iPhone's Bluetooth log and pull the coordinates from the last connection.  How can I do this?**  I'm decently savvy with this programming but mostly in Python which obviously won't directly help in this situation.

Please help.

My iPhone specs:

Model Name: iPhone Xs

Software Version: 13.3

I'm willing to jailbreak my phone if there is a way to access these files.

Comment: You’ll need a Apple Developer account and Xcode to access the logs. See:  https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/profiles-and-logs/. There’s also no guarantee that logging was enabled at the time (because it’s for debugging) so you may be out of luck.